# How to centralize elements inside an <ul>?

Tags: html, css

Well, I have a site and it's happening something that I just can't fix.
I have a code like this:

```css
aside {
   font-size: 150%;
   font-family: fantasy;
   font-variant: small-caps;
   line-height: 2em;
   background: rgba(187,219,136,0.75);
   width: 90%;
   height: 50px;
   text-align: center;
}

aside {
   margin: auto;
   margin-top: 20px;
}

aside li {
   float: left;
   padding: 0 2%;
   font-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<aside>
      <ul>
        <li id="matematica"><a href="matematica.html" title="Ver resumos de Matemática">Matemática</a></li>
        <li><a href="geografia.html" title="Ver resumos de Geografia">Geografia</a></li>
        <li><a href="fisica.html" title="Ver resumos de Física">Física</a></li>
        <li><a href="historia.html" title="Ver resumos de História">História</a></li>
        <li><a href="portugues.html" title="Ver resumos de Português">Português</a></li>
        <li id="quimica"><a href="quimica.html" title="Ver resumos de Química">Química</a></li>
      </ul>
</aside>
```

So, the problem is that I want to centralize the li elements inside the ul, and I can't use **text align** because li is not text!
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Remove the float on the `li`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Text align of an unordered list item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328489/text-align-of-an-unordered-list-item)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this what you want?

```css
aside {
      font-size: 150%;
      font-family: fantasy;
      font-variant: small-caps;
      line-height: 2em;
     background: rgba(187,219,136,0.75);
     width: 90%;
     height: 100px;
     text-align: center;
    }
    aside{
      margin: auto;
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
    aside li{
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 0 2%;
      font-size: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<aside>
      <ul>
        <li id="matematica"><a href="matematica.html" title="Ver resumos de Matemática">Matemática</a></li>
        <li><a href="geografia.html" title="Ver resumos de Geografia">Geografia</a></li>
        <li><a href="fisica.html" title="Ver resumos de Física">Física</a></li>
        <li><a href="historia.html" title="Ver resumos de História">História</a></li>
        <li><a href="portugues.html" title="Ver resumos de Português">Português</a></li>
        <li id="quimica"><a href="quimica.html" title="Ver resumos de Química">Química</a></li>
      </ul>
    </aside>
```

Comment: Yeah, that is exactly what I want. Thank you a lot :)

Comment: can you green tick(accept the solution) the answer so every one knows that this is working answer.

Answer (score 0):

try to :

```
aside li{
 display:inline-block;
 padding: 0 2%;
 font-size: 100%;
}
```

remove the float too ;

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you want to achieve, you may try changing:

```
aside li{
  float: left;
  padding: 0 2%;
  font-size: 100%;
}
```

to

```
aside li{
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 2%;
  font-size: 100%;
}
```

See it on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h3t3hdt0/) and, also, check the attribute [`list-style-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type) for your `<ul>` tag.